# How to detect that an i2c slave doesn't respond to the master on PIC18f

Tags: pic, i2c

I have an PIC18f i2c Master and some other devices as slaves.

I want to detect if a slave is not on the bus or if he doesn't responds.

Right now, the communication Master<->Slaves works well except when a slave doesn't responds. When this happens, the PIC stays in a waiting state and the whole program is stopped.

How can I detect and fix that ? (In a software way)

For information, I'm working on a PIC18f25k22.

Comment: Consider asking on the [electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site. When you do so, explain what "a issue occurs" and "is bugging" mean.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But it is a programming problem. I don't want to fix that with electronics (if possible).
I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using MPLAB with C18. The source for all the I2C functions can be found in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\mplabc18\v3.46\src\pmc_common\i2c`

Next, you'll need to figure out what functions are hanging and then write your own versions that don't go into endless loops if the slave doesn't respond. Most like `ReadI2C` is hanging waiting for a slave to respond. So you could replace it with `myReadI2C` that takes a timeout parameter. A modified version of the code in i2c_read.c.

```
#if defined (I2C_V1)
int myReadI2C( long timeout )
{
if( ((SSPCON1&0x0F)==0x08) || ((SSPCON1&0x0F)==0x0B) )  //master mode only
  SSPCON2bits.RCEN = 1;           // enable master for 1 byte reception
  while ( !SSPSTATbits.BF && timeout > 0) timeout--;      // wait until byte received  
  return timeout == 0 ? (-1) : ( SSPBUF );              // return with read byte 
}
#endif

#if defined (I2C_V4)
int myReadI2C( long timeout)
{
  while ( !SSPSTATbits.BF && timeout > 0) timeout--;      // wait until byte received  
  return timeout == 0 ? (-1) : ( SSPBUF );              // return with read byte 
}
#endif
```

`myReadI2C` will return -1 on timeout and unsigned char value (0 - 255) on success. You will need to modify the other I2C functions you use in a similar way to avoid loops that only test register status values. As for a value for timeout, you need to find a value through experimentation depending on your devices clock speed and your peripherals response time.

Comment: Thank you. I use XC8 instead of C18 but I suppose it's the same.

Comment: I haven't used XC8, but I would assume it is similar.